# IntelliJ new Ant Build results in code that can't find JDK?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I'm using a fresh install of IntelliJ and got a 64 bit of JDK 1.8. Making a simple HelloWorld program compiles and runs fine, so the JDK should be installed properly. However, running an new Ant Build results in a failure where the module.xml and other xml files generated when using a new Ant build results in this mess:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Lzb.jpg

How can I properly start a new Ant build. The PATH to ANT_HOME isn't working properly, but the error messages in the image I provided seems to show that it can't find the JDK, which I do set in Project Settings.

Comment: Make sure the module is using the project JDK. Do you mean Ant can't find the JDK?

Comment: I think that Ant can't find the JDK. Do I need to add the JDK to the PATH to do it?

Comment: Are you using Ant version bundled into Intellij?

Comment: I went to main-> build -> generate ant build, if thats what you mean.